# Can't get the value of a custom attr in jquery

Tags: jquery, attr

I have this div :

```
    <div id="test"  hhh="o" ></div>
```

however, I'm trying to get the value of my custom attribute hhh like this

```
    alert($("#test").attr("hhh"));
```

but I'm getting "undefined" instead. could you tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: sorry, they are both "hhh"

Comment: [It appears to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/e04rdqaq/). Are you wrapping it in `$(document).ready`? Does only one `#test` exist on the page? (You can check with `alert($("[id='test']").length)`

Comment: This works unless #test doesn't exist when you call your alert()

Comment: works fine here...bet you forgot to wait for element to exist http://jsfiddle.net/e47zk8Lm/

Comment: yeah I did all of that, the funny thing s that it works ok when I try to show ("id") instead of my customized attribute

Comment: create a demo that replicates your problem ... nothing wrong with code shown

Comment: On a side note.. if you want your html to validate, you should prefix custom attribute tags with "data-". So your custom attribute would be data-hhh="o"

Comment: Ok.. I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min, I've changed it to jquery-1.11.3.min, now the alert doesn't even appear!

Comment: @charlietfl I guess you''re right.. the problem is with waiting the element to exist, but I've put it inside a .live function, shouldn't it be able to handle it?